# PowerPivot get excluded data from Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, powerpivot

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwJST.png)

I have a Access, which has more than 1 million rows of data, as you can see from the screenshot. I want to dedupe the data in term of BRUIDREQID, as it has duplicates. Is there any way that when I connect data from Access to PowerPivot, I can get deduped dataset?

What I am doing now is using Python to dedupe the data and extract it as a csv file. I want to know whether I can use PowerPivot instead and save more time to dedupe large data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing the Access database, you should be able to write arbitrary SQL, and you could just do a

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
* 
FROM Table
```

, which would de-dupe the table.

Power Pivot does not offer any functionality to change the existing data in a table once imported - you cannot add or remove rows, nor can you alter the values of any imported fields.

Comment: Actually, my access file touches the 2 GB line, so I cannot make any query or table. That's why I want to input the data into PowerPivot and then dedupe under PP. Anyway, you answer at least let me know I cannot do that based on PP. I used Python to complete that. Thanks